# NoSuchMethodError occurs while trying to connect to Cloud Bigtable from a Cloud Dataflow worker

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I set up a Cloud Dataflow Pipeline in accordance with this article: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/dataflow-hbase

When I submit it to the Cloud Dataflow managed service, I got the following error at a Cloud Dataflow worker:

```
Uncaught exception in main thread. Exiting with status code 1.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient()Lcom/google/bigtable/repackaged/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslContextBuilder;
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableSession.createSslContext(BigtableSession.java:98)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableSession.access$000(BigtableSession.java:82)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableSession$1.run(BigtableSession.java:151)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How should I handle this problem?

My Cloud Dataflow Pipeline source code is the following:

```
package mypackage

import com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow.CloudBigtableIO;
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow.CloudBigtableOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow.CloudBigtableTableConfiguration;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.Create;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;

public class Main {
    // Create a DoFn that creates a Put or Delete.  MUTATION_TRANSFORM is a simplistic example.
    static final DoFn<String, Mutation> MUTATION_TRANSFORM = new DoFn<String, Mutation>() {
        @Override
        public void processElement(DoFn<String, Mutation>.ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            c.output(new Put(c.element().getBytes()).addColumn("v".getBytes(), "v".getBytes(), "value".getBytes()));
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // CloudBigtableOptions is one way to retrieve the options.  It's not required to use this
        // specific PipelineOptions extension; CloudBigtableOptions is there as a convenience.
        CloudBigtableOptions options =
                PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(CloudBigtableOptions.class);

        // CloudBigtableTableConfiguration contains the project, zone, cluster and table to connect to
        CloudBigtableTableConfiguration config = CloudBigtableTableConfiguration.fromCBTOptions(options);

        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
        // This sets up serialization for Puts and Deletes so that Dataflow can potentially move them through
        // the network
        CloudBigtableIO.initializeForWrite(p);

        p
                .apply(Create.of("Hello", "World"))
                .apply(ParDo.of(MUTATION_TRANSFORM))
                .apply(CloudBigtableIO.writeToTable(config));

        p.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is the same as: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/613

I think that the problem here is that both Dataflow and Bigtable include io.grpc.  Bigtable uses the shading plugin and changes package names, but didn't change the io.grpc package names, as described here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/582

Your best bet to get around the problem is to use the 0.2.3-SNAPSHOT version of bigtable-hbase.  You'll have to add the following in your pom.xml to be able to use SNAPSHOTs:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>snapshots-repo</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

We'll release an official version ASAP in the new year.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I could put records to Cloud Bigtable successfully by using 0.2.3-SNAPSHOT version of bigtable-hbase-dataflow.

I'm looking forward to getting an official version.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like the appropriate jar file is not available on the workers. Is it on your local classpath?

By default, Dataflow copies the contents of the classpath from the main program into Google Cloud Storage before launching the job on the Dataflow Service. Then the workers grab the jars from Google Cloud Storage. You can see this happening in the logs from your main program:

```
INFO: PipelineOptions.filesToStage was not specified. Defaulting to files from the classpath: will stage XX files. Enable logging at DEBUG level to see which files will be staged.
...
INFO: Uploading XX files from PipelineOptions.filesToStage to staging location to prepare for execution.
INFO: Uploading PipelineOptions.filesToStage complete: YY files newly uploaded, ZZ files cached
...
Submitted job: 2015-12-28_07_22_37-8675309
```

Comment: Happened to me when I had a different version of netty being imported in pom.xml. This was resolved by either excluding the offending version or the one provided by the hbase-bigtable client library.